# Distribution of variable sized images/boxes(only aspect ratio given) on a 2D area

Tags: cg.comp-geom, optimization, packing

I'm trying to find a solution for the following problem. 
You have a set of pictures or let us assume they are just **boxes** with a given **aspect ratio**. And you have a two-dimensional **area** with width and height. 
The boxes can vary in size only their aspect ratio is fixed, BUT they can have also have a max/min size (optional).

I'm looking for an optimal distribution of the boxes in this area, so that the remaining area is minimal.

Is there a solution to this problem, or a best practice to deal with it? Or are there any papers published on that topic?
(some toolkit for javascript dealing with this problem would be brilliant)

What I already found during my short research? Similar problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129221/treemapping-with-a-given-aspect-ratio

I have also thought about a mathematical solution to this problem and what I came up with so far was:

```
x1+...+xn <= x_dimension            | x1..xn (box width)
a1*x1+...+an*xn <= y_dimension      | a1..an (aspect ratio)
```

of course there are multiple solution to this problem so what you then need to do is to find out which is the best. So you need to find:

```
min(x_remainder*y_remainder)
```

whereas

```
(x1+...+xn) - x_dimension = x_remainder 
(a1*x1+...+an*xn) - y_dimension  = y_remainder
```

I'm not even sure if I'm on the right path with this approach, so I would also be grateful, if someone could provide me with some food for thought.

Comment: In general, this is called packing. To get you going, check the [Wikipedia article on packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem).

Comment: And this particular version of the problem is called 2-dimensional packing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is called the (2-dimensional) packing problem. Your problem (Rectangle packing) is NP-complete. It can be shown with a reduction from the Bin Packing problem. See for example this paper [Richard E. Korf: Optimal Rectangle Packing: Initial Results](http://www.aaai.org/Papers/ICAPS/2003/ICAPS03-029.pdf). Here's a [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210979/Fast-optimizing-rectangle-packing-algorithm-for-bu) that describes an algorithm (the same basic idea as in the paper) in quite a bit of detail. In addition, the paper mentions the problem can be modeled as a constraint satisfaction problem (CSP), so you might be interested in using a CSP-solver if you need to solve the problem in practice. One such solver I have used is [MINION](http://minion.sourceforge.net/).